# How to call a node js function from a separate front end javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I have a node js backend (app.js), which is connected to a html, css, and javascript (script.js) front end.

In my HTML I have a form that gets an image, which then calls a function in script.js.

Script.js then uploads the file using ajax and jquery, which works fine.

Once that's complete, I want it to automatically call a function I have in app.js that calls a python script.

This function works on its own, but I'm having problems connecting both the file upload and the python script.  Right now I get an error when I upload the image that says that app is not defined.  How can I call both of these in one function?

Relevant HTML:

```
<form id="form">
     Select your image: <input type="file"  name="myfile" id="myfile" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg"><br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="getCodeButton"/>
 </form>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Relevant node js (app.js):

```
const express = require('express')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const multer  = require('multer')
    const sharp = require('sharp')
    
    const app = express()
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    app.use(express.static('./public')) 
    app.use(express.static('./uploads/'))
    
    app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
        res.sendFile("index.html", { root: __dirname + "/public" })
    })
    
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
    app.listen(port, 
        ()=>console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`))
        
    const upload = multer().single('myfile')
    app.post('/upload', (req, res)=>{
        upload(req, res, async function(err){ 
         if( err|| req.file === undefined){
             console.log(err)
             res.send("error occured")
         }else{
            let fileName = "myfile.jpeg"
            var image = await sharp(req.file.buffer)
            .jpeg({
                quality: 40,
            }).toFile('./uploads/'+fileName)
            .catch( err => { console.log('error: ', err) })
            res.send(req.body)
         }
        })
    })
app.get('/runPython1', (req, res) => {
 
    var dataToSend;
    const python = spawn('python', ['qr_vision.py', 'uploads/myfile.jpeg']);
    python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
    dataToSend = data.toString();
    });
    python.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
    //console.log(dataToSend)
    res.send(dataToSend)
    });
 
})
```

Relevant javascript (script.js):

```
document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 'sent'+this.responseText+ xhttp.status;
      }else{
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = xhttp.status ;
      }
    }

    xhttp.open("POST", "upload")
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('myfile', document.getElementById('myfile').files[0])
    xhttp.send(formData)
    
    app.get('/runPython1', (req, res) => {
        console.log(res.result)
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call both of these in one function"? And *where* does it say `app` is undefined? If you want to run the Python shell out after the file is uploaded why is it in a separate function? Unrelated, but if this is meant for more than one person to use at a time you'll have a problem with the file naming.

Comment: Client-side, you don't want `app.get('/runPython1')` - that's server-side code.  Instead, you need to make an Ajax call to `/runPython1` and get the result back from the server.  You can use the `fetch()` interface in the browser for making that Ajax call.

Comment: I want to be able to be able to upload and then run the script one after another. It says that app is undefined in the browser console.  My apologies for the vague wording.  
At the moment, I'm only running locally and have no plans for multiple users, but I will keep that in mind when I expand!  Thank you!

Comment: The client knows *nothing* about the server-side code except for the endpoints; you'd make a *request* to the back end endpoint, just like you make the first request to the back end endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in several ways

1. From frontend: Write an another XMLHttpRequest to call runPython1 endpoint and send the request once the upload one is completed.
2. From nodejs backend: Instead of exposing runPython1 as api endpoint, you can have it as function and call it once the upload is completed.

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res)=>{
        upload(req, res, async function(err){ 
         if( err|| req.file === undefined){
             console.log(err)
             res.send("error occured")
         }else{
            let fileName = "myfile.jpeg"
            var image = await sharp(req.file.buffer)
            .jpeg({
                quality: 40,
            }).toFile('./uploads/'+fileName)
            .catch( err => { console.log('error: ', err) })
            runPython1(res);
         }
        })
    })

const runPython1 = (res) => {
 
    var dataToSend;
    const python = spawn('python', ['qr_vision.py', 'uploads/myfile.jpeg']);
    python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
    dataToSend = data.toString();
    });
    python.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
    //console.log(dataToSend)
    res.send(dataToSend)
    });
 
}
```

3. You can also redirect to runPython1 endpoint once the upload finished. Refer [This site](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/redirect#:%7E:text=The%20res.,new%20URL%20as%20shown%20below.) for redirecting

Comment: For your second way, how would I go about making it a function and calling it?

Comment: I can't post lengthy message in comment so i edit the answer itself